# HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: php, wordpress

I have imported my site from a local to a live server and this error has come up for only 4 of my images and it worked perfect on the local server.

> Warning:
>   getimagesize(http://localhost/theshavingsaloonNEW/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/step1.jpg)
>   [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
>   /nfs/c11/h03/mnt/206312/domains/theshavingsaloon.com/html/wp-content/plugins/wr-pagebuilder/shortcodes/image/image.php
>   on line 223

Here is the if statement around line 223 if it helps

```
if ($image_file) {
    $image_id = WR_Pb_Helper_Functions::get_image_id($image_file);
    $attachment = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $image_id );
    $image_file = (!empty( $attachment['sizes'][$image_size]['url'])) ? $attachment['sizes'][$image_size]['url'] : $image_file;
    $data = getimagesize( $image_file );
    $width = $data[0];
    $height = $data[1];
    $html_elemments .= "<img width='{$width}' height='{$height}' src='{$image_file}'{$alt_text}{$class_img} />";
    $script = '';
    $target = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://localhost/theshavingsaloonNEW
```

this is a localhost url rather than a production one. Try these options in order to solve:

1. update wp address urls in the admin dashboard -> settings -> general, there are two to change.
2. Perform a sqldump of the db and use a text editor to replace localhost with your domain and then re-upload.
3. Download the current theme folder / child theme if you have custom templates or made the theme yourself and use a text editor to find any instances of `http://localhost`. Replace with `get_site_url()./restofurl`
4. In future use a migrate plugin to make this easy, it will do the db work for you.

Comment: Thank you for relying to my query ! I have replaced localhost in my db with my domain name however i can't find any instances of local host in either my themes folder or my child-theme folder ? Is that normal as the error is still coming up and now more aspects of the edited theme have disappeared ?

Comment: Warning: getimagesize(http://theshavingsaloon.com/theshavingsaloonNEW/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/step1.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /nfs/c11/h03/mnt/206312/domains/theshavingsaloon.com/html/wp-content/plugins/wr-pagebuilder/shortcodes/image/image.php on line 223          -   and this is the error now

Comment: there should be no localhost refs in your theme. You should use get_site_url() to get the correct home url. As you can see from the url you have posted, wp now thinks your url is http://theshavingsaloon.com/theshavingsaloonNEW, have you prepended theshavingsaloonNEW in front of any urls? search your theme for this as well. also check any constants that have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

As I can guess You have left the image urls hardcoded for your 'localhost'.
You should use `plugin_dir_url()` method for generating the url automatically.
See [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) link for function information on codex.

P.S. Also, you can use `wp_get_template_directory_uri() . 'your-path-relative-to-/wp-content/themes/'` for using in theme template files.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong URL of the image is being passed through the `getimagesize` function. It seems it is taking the local url of the image.

You should check if `$image_file` contains the right url of image.